# Transition Animation From Fragment To Activity Android

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, fragment

In my application, I want to transit from Fragment to Activity.

For this purpose I am using following code for Animation,

```
Bundle bndlanimation =ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slideinleft,R.anim.slideinright).toBundle();
startActivity(intentonboard,bndlanimation);
```

This works fine.
But What I want to do is that, I am moving from Fragment To Activity.
So I just want to apply the exit animation for Fragment only. Next Activity should be added behind the scene without animation.

So What Should I write in place of enter animation ?
I tried with **0** instead of **R.anim.slideinright**. But It effects on Exit animation.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of 0, create new animation without any parameter changes and replace that R.anim.slideinright.

Answer (score 3):

> if you in fragment Layout and wanna to get intent to same activity you must use this...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivty.class);
startActivity(intent);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your knowledge! This looks like a helpful answer, particularly with the code sample you provided, but I'm not sure where the first quote comes from. If you're quoting someone else it would be helpful to link to their post. If it's your own words then remove the angle bracket at the start to show that it's not a quote.

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_in_from_left, R.animator.slide_in_from_right);
```

Use **getActivity()**  After **startActivity(intent);**

May this help you.